# UUIDString unexpectedly found nil

Tags: swift, ibeacon, option-type

I am working on a piece of code using `CoreLocation` and `CLBeaconRegion`, but I'm receiving an error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I want to create a region variable holding a `CLBeaconRegion` like so:

```
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "AM_2015-06-10")!, identifier: "AnyMorning")
```

A bit later in my code, I am calling:

```
locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
```

And when I launch the app, I receive the above error. What is the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

`"AM_2015-06-10"` is not a valid UUIDString! so
`NSUUID(UUIDString: "AM_2015-06-10")!` will crash your application

> UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers), also known as GUIDs (Globally
>   Unique Identifiers) or IIDs (Interface Identifiers), are 128-bit
>   values.

Comment: I have used `000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` as example now in my app, but that still crashes with the same error?

Comment: That is still too short.  A UUID must have 16 bytes.  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: That was indeed the solution, thank you, davidgyoung!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. Yes the above answer is correct. Make sure your UUID is 8 characters - 4 characters - 4 characters - 4 characters - 12 characters

The characters should be 0-9 or a-f